# ¿Quiénes son los más afectados por el ustedeo?

Tags: selección-de-palabras, formalidad, ustedeo

He encontrado que varias veces, mi empleo del español en conversación es afectado por el llamado "ustedeo".  Afecta mis relaciones con gente que acabo de conocer, porque muchas personas piensan que deseo comunicar formalidad y distancia cuando no es así.

Yo no sé de dónde viene mi tendencia hacia *ustedeo*.  Aprendí el español de niño en Sudamérica, pero es un segundo idioma.  Hasta hace poco atribuía mi costumbre al hecho de que mis mayores me enseñaron a tratar a los adultos siempre de "usted".  Y como no pasé los años de mi adolescencia en comunidades de habla española, no cambié de costumbre.

Pero acabo de leer el artículo llamado [*Español bogotano*](http://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Espa%C3%B1ol_bogotano) en Wikipedia, donde aprendí la palabra "ustedeo".  Se me occurre que posiblemente la gente de Medellín me enseñó el ustedeo.  Así que quiero saber más acerca de quiénes son los más afectados por el ustedeo, así como si hay otros que emplean el "tú" con demasiada frecuencia.

Comment: En España se tiende a tutear en la vida diaria. Por lo general, cualquier hablante latinoamericano usa más el "usted" de lo que se hace en España.

Comment: Es de destacar que no en toda España es similar el uso de usted, en Canarias se utiliza mucho más el usted que en la península.

Comment: No entiendo esta parte: "emplean el *tú* con demasiada confianza."

Comment: Mi duda era si habia gente que usa el tuteo cuando usted era lo mâs correcto.  Parece que no.

Comment: @WalterMitty cuál es su lengua nativa y en cuál país aprendió el español?

Comment: @aparente001 para muchas personas de ciertas regiones de América hispanohablante la interacción entre hablantes es usando "usted" y el uso del tuteo se considera que es un abuso de confianza.

Comment: M lengua nativa es inglės.  Aprendí español en Chile, de niño.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Los españoles percibimos que los sudamericanos abusan del "usted" incluso en situaciones de poca formalidad. Supongo que tienen la costumbre de usarlo más a menudo. Como otros comentan, incluso en algunas regiones se usa el "vos", no usado para nada en España.

En España el "usted" se usa en situaciones de mucha formalidad y en primeros encuentros laborales/formales. Sin embargo en cualquier otro contexto es considerado un abuso de formalidad y el tuteo se considera correcto casi desde el primer momento en relaciones laborales.

Comment: Gracias por la respuests.  Diría que el tuteo es más frecuente en México y en el Caribe que en Sudamérica.

Comment: en algunas regiones de españa se sigue usando el voseo

Comment: No obstante, existen regiones como Canarias, donde curiosamente se utiliza el ustedes en lugar del vosotros, pero en cambio solo se usa usted en vez de tu cuando la situación requiere formalidad.

Answer (score 8):

Chiste que muestra la amplia diferencia entre "usted" y "tu":

El director general de un banco se preocupaba por un joven director estrella que después de un periodo de trabajar junto a él, sin parar nunca, ni para almorzar, empieza a ausentarse al mediodía. Entonces el director general del banco llama al detective privado del banco y le dice:

"Siga a López una semana entera, no vaya a ser que ande en algo malo o sucio”.

El detective cumple con el cometido, vuelve e informa:
 “López sale normalmente al mediodía, toma su coche, va a su casa a almorzar, luego le hace el amor a su mujer, se fuma uno de sus excelentes habanos y vuelve a trabajar”.

Responde el director: Ah, bueno , menos mal, no hay nada malo en todo eso!!!!.

Luego el detective pregunta: “¿Puedo tutearlo, señor?”.

Sorprendido, el director responde: “Sí, cómo no”.

Y, entonces, el detective le dice: Te repito: López sale normalmente al mediodía, toma tu coche, va a tu casa a almorzar, luego le hace el amor a tu mujer, se fuma uno de tus excelentes habanos y vuelve a trabajar”.

Comment: :-D No es que esto responda la pregunta, pero es muy bueno.

Comment: de acuerdo no responde pero aclara el uso y la ambigüedad .

Answer (score 5):

En Argentina y Uruguay, en casi cualquier situación, incluso con desconocidos, se usa el "vos". El "usted" es sólo para casos formales, como ser al referirse a un superior en el trabajo o a un profesor, aunque aún en esos ambientes en muchos casos también se usa "vos".

En otros países latinoamericanos, diría que el "usted" formal es un poco más utilizado, por ejemplo, con un desconocido.

En algunos otros lugares, "usted" a veces se utiliza con una connotación cariñosa.

Comment: Bienvenido a SLSE. +1. Lo que mencionas de Colombia no es del todo correcto. Lee la respuesta de @juansero29 que menciona algo al respecto.

Comment: quise decir, en algunos casos, no significa que sea cariñoso con todo el mundo, pero entre padre/madre e hijo/hija, tio/sobrino, etc.

Answer (score 4):

En **Bogotá, Colombia**, es demasiado frecuente el "ustedear" de hombre a hombre bajo casi toda circunstancia. Tanto que incluso para mí, bogotano de nacimiento, es demasiado.

Puede que conozcas a una persona desde hace muchísimo tiempo, que sea tu mejor amigo y se tengan muchísima confianza; aún así, el tutearse de hombre a hombre es mal visto socialmente en Bogotá. De manera general, los hombres solo tutean a las mujeres (respetando las mismas circunstancias de edad, jerarquía, clase económica, etc que tú mencionaste). En lo personal, el único hombre que tuteo estando en Bogotá es mi padre, y sé que muchos otros hombres bogotanos no lo harían con sus padres.

Creo que en varias regiones y ciudades de Colombia existe este mismo fenómeno, pero no a la misma escala, como en Santander, Boyacá, Tolima, Pasto y la totalidad de la región Andina.

En Medellín o Cali, por ejemplo, hay mucha gente que "vosea", lo que reduce el "ustedeo". El vosear es visto, al menos en Colombia, como algo más informal y cercano al "tutear". Bogotá es entonces para mí una de las ciudades más afectadas por el "ustedeo", ves niños de seis y siete años "ustedear" a sus amigos de barrio cuando juegan fútbol en los parques; nunca escucharas un "tú" entre dos hombres en un colegio y rara vez en una universidad, jamás podrás "tutear" a tus mejores amigos y lo mismo puede ocurrir entre un grupo de niñas, aunque es menos frecuente... en fin.

Es muy raro escuchar a un hombre tutear a otro hombre. Cuando sucede es muy frecuente que sea la persona mayor o en una posición jerárquica más alta quien tutea a una persona menor o con menos poder, o que sea una persona adinerada quien tutea, sin que sea correspondido. Muchas veces, los hombres homosexuales también tutean a todo el mundo, razón por la cual (en mi opinión) muchos hombres heterosexuales evitan de utilizar el "tú" en la práctica.

Si buscas una ciudad bien "usteadera", esa es **Bogotá**.

Comment: Completamente de acuerdo on @DGaleano. Nací y he estado toda mi vida en Bogotá, se usa ampliamente el "usted", en particular para el trato entre hombres: padres, hermanos, tíos, primos. También en casos de jerarquía laboral o administrativa: de empleados a jefes, de fieles al párroco; el tutear se usa más con la pareja, las hijas, los hijos. Se considera abuso de confianza el tuteo. También he escuchado mucho el "usted" en personas de la zona antioqueña.

Comment: Difiero en la afirmación "mas afectado", más bien el uso extendido del "usted" permite conservar la distancia apropiada y respeto entre las personas.

Comment: "Muchas veces, los hombres homosexuales también tutean a todo el mundo". Una opinión realmente mala venida.

Comment: ¿Mal avenida @Lambie? ¿Por qué?

Answer (score 3):

Diría que en España se utiliza únicamente en situaciones de mucha formalidad (una entrevista de trabajo, por ejemplo) o para mostrar respeto, como cuando se habla con personas mayores, se pregunta a un desconocido por una dirección, o una conversación telefónica con una persona desconocida.

Por el contrario en Sudamérica se utiliza por defecto.

Answer (score 1):

In the 20th Century, Spanish language scholars looked at the issues of *el tuteo* and *el voseo*.  "Ustedeo" is an inside-out twist at looking at honorific usted / ustedes forms of the 3rd conjugation. I recommend any student of Spanish to research *voseo*, as it is not typically taught in school, even though 40% of Latin Americans use the *voseo*.

Once you learn about *tuteo* and *voseo*, you will understand enough about Ud./Uds. to figure out the rest, and avoid looking at the same cow through a different window.

Answer (score 1):

Las reglas de tutear, ustedear, y vosear varían por país.  No hay una regla fija.  España me parece un país muy informal y México mucho más formal.  El primero es probablemente verdad por ser un país de Europa. Ese último es probablemente resultado de tener una herencia lingüística indígena con reglas de formalidad bien complejas y también resultado de los tiempos coloniales cuando la gente tenía que mostrar respeto según su clase- español, criollo, mestizo, o indígena.

Tiene que haber un estudio lingüística al tanto...

Comment: México el más formal??

Comment: @lambie Cambié una letra.

Answer (score 0):

En Canarias es muy común el uso de "usted" hasta en situaciones totalmente informales. Cuando viajo a cualquier otra provincia española siempre surge la duda de por qué trato de "usted" y siempre tengo que explicar que no se trata de un formalismo en si.

Comment: Lo que pasa en Canarias es que no existe el "vosotros" y se sustituye siempre por "ustedes". Pero en singular existe tanto "tu" como "usted".